# On mac: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)

Tags: java, macos, oracle, tomcat, jndi

I'm developing a little application in Adobe Flex witch connects to a tomcat servlet for taking the data from the Oracle DB.
The Flex App connects to Servlet (localhost->localhost) but servlet cannot reach to Oracle DB (localhost->Another Machine in LAN).
I tried using the Oracle SQLDeveloper (which is developed in Java) and it works fine.

It works fine on Windows PC (tomcat in Eclipse), but when i used my Mac (also tomcat in Eclipse) the servlet gave me the error...

This is my context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/Anagrafica">
<Resource name="jdbc/SimplyAnagraficaDS" 
             auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource"
             url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:PORT:SID"
             username="test" 
             password="test" 
             driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
             maxActive="8" />
</Context>
```

This is the method that take the connection:

```
    public static Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    Context ic = new InitialContext();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ic
            .lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/SimplyAnagraficaDS");
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

and this is the StackTrace (on          return dataSource.getConnection();        )

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Errore di I/O: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at com.arcangelovicedomini.simplyanagrafica.dbservice.DataBaseService.getConnection(DataBaseService.java:108)
at com.arcangelovicedomini.simplyanagrafica.services.PersonaService.getListPersona(PersonaService.java:66)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at flex.messaging.services.remoting.adapters.JavaAdapter.invoke(JavaAdapter.java:418)
at flex.messaging.services.RemotingService.serviceMessage(RemotingService.java:183)
at flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeMessageToService(MessageBroker.java:1400)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:1011)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166)
at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.service(MessageBrokerServlet.java:353)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Errore di I/O: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
... 40 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:126)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:460)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:161)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
... 52 more
```

I have no firewall. So... I really can't understand what is happening. (I tried everything. Changing configuration, changing tomcat bin...)

In tomcat\lib there is ojdbc7.jar for connecting to DB.

I'm using jdk 1.7 u75 and Tomcat 7 with Oracle 10g.

On the Windows machine I'm also using jdk 1.7u75 with Tomcat 7.

Comment: Can you reach the DB listener port directly from the Mac - from terminal, `telnet <IP> <port>`? If so are you sure Tomcat is picking up the configuration, and isn't using a different or stale context.xml?

Comment: Yeah, with telnet I can reach the db..
I'm sure, in debug mode I viewed the dataSource variable and it's content and there was the correct configuration to DB.

Comment: Well, the `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out` seems to suggest it's not connecting to the same address or port as you telnet'd to (or rather less likely, is trying to connect *from* a different interface); given the timeout rather than rejection I'd suspect the address is very slightly different, but you seem to have ruled that out already. On the information given I'm not sure I can help you much, sorry...

Comment: I have the thunderbolt eth adapter (originally from Apple) and WiFi card disabled... So it MUST use the eth to connect to DB... The address must be the DB address, I never edited that.